# Tensorflow: time series forecasting

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, multi-step

I used the tensorflow time series forecasting from this page:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series
with a few other datasets.
It is working fine, except for the multi-step and auto recursive models.
With the tensorflow example dataset (jena_climate_2009_2016), I get
T(deg) predictions like this:

[image]

With all stock OHLC times series I tried, I get Close predictions like this:

[image]

The (val) loss are similar in each case.

I can not figure out why the predictions are so "linear" with OHLC datasets.